# Do I need to freeze my rye flour?

Tags: flour, storage, rye

I got ten pounds of rye flour from the amish store yesterday. They only had a single, two-pound bag sitting on the shelf but, when asked, the man behind the counter said they actually have lots of rye flour but keep it all in the freezer because otherwise Something Bad will happen to it. It's organic and I think it might be wholemeal but I'm not sure.

I haven't been baking for terribly long, maybe 8 months or a year, but I've never frozen my rye flour. Is this a legitimate need? Ten pounds of flour takes up more freezer space than I would prefer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rye flour should be stored in the fridge or freezer. This is because the cold air will slow down the oxidation process which is what makes the flour turn rancid.  It will keep in the freezer for up to 6 months, slightly less in the fridge. Just give it a sniff when using it to make sure it is still fine.

Make sure it is properly sealed before storing it because from my own experience, it has resulted in the flour tasting and smelling like the freezer (other food etc). Use an airtight plastic or glass container.

Comment: I store mine on the cabinet in a hermetically sealed container. It takes about a year before it starts smelling manky. Don't know if it's full grain or wholemeal. I go through about 5 Lbs (2.6kg) per year. I would not trust it in one of those leaky metal tins or ceramic flour vessels. They're a sure way to invite flour beetles and the like. Plastic lid or some other hermetic seal are you best bet. If someone gave me 10 pounds of the stuff, 5 pounds would go, very well sealed into the freezer. -It's a nice replacement for about half the white/wheat flour in cornbread,